# how to trigger visibility change to child controls with a trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I have a databound listbox thet generates items in a datatemplate of type wrappanel with other controls within it. I would like to have the behavior to, when I change the visibility to affect differently the controls within the wrappanel

```
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding .}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding editMode, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Label Width="150" Content="{Binding Path=avaiableAttribute.Text}" Name="lblName"/>
                    <Label Width="150" 
                           Content="{Binding Path=informationItem.ItemString, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                           Initialized="Label_Initialized" 
                           Name="lblText" />
                    <ContentPresenter MinWidth="200" MaxHeight="200" Content="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource InformationItemConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Name="cpValue"
                                      Initialized="ContentPresenter_Initialized"/>

                    <WrapPanel.Style>
                        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type WrapPanel}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" >
                                    <Trigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter TargetName="lblText" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="cpValue" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </Trigger.Setters>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </WrapPanel.Style>
    </WrapPanel>
```

I just get the following build error

> the property 'targetname' does not represent a valid target for the 'setter' because an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `Setter`, the `TargetName` only applies to elements in a `Template`. This means your `Trigger` has to exist in a `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate`. The easiest way to do what you want to do is to create your own `IValueConverter` for the inverse of `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` (ie return `Visibility.Collapsed` when value is true).

Comment: did exactly that as a quick and dirty temporary solution.